# Best way to convert an already-existing ArcGIS Javascript Map Application to an Offline Windows Application

Tags: javascript, offline, arcgis-js-api, offlineapps

I currently have a working ArcGIS JavaScript map application with a lot of functionality with it.  I found out that some of our engineers who will be using the web map in the field will sometimes not have internet access and I have been asked to look into ways to create an offline version of the application.  I know this is possible using ArcGIS SDK methods, but I do not know those languages and how I would go from JavaScript to those languages.  I am wondering what the best way to convert an ArcGIS JavaScript application to an Offline Windows Application would be if there is one.  If anyone has experience doing this, advice would be extremely appreciated!  Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

If the people in the field have IIS, you could install a local version on the computer/tablet they are going to be using.

Comment: But they would still need access to the internet to be able to use the map service for the map application.

Comment: I guess if the whole thing can't run locally, then you'll have to go a different route.